# React + Redux Saga refresh and re-render list when MongoDB data changes

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

I wanted the list of users to always be in sync with the MongoDB database, 
I created an action that dispatches a refresh call to refresh the list of users.

What I have right now is an interval that dispatches the refresh call to refresh the list every 1 second, but I think it's a little hack to do that.

Is there a better way to refresh my list and re-render them through my React views?

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing right now is okay but is expensive, specially if your browser tab is not active (please note that setInterval/setTimeout get less priority by browser if the tab is inactive or minimized).

You might need to explore using RxJS which has the capability to create periodic caller functions and you can subscribe to it in your react view.

Example - https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/interval.html